# Change the alpha value of body when side menu is opened

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-color, alpha

I have set the background-color for body tag in css using rgba values. I want to change the alpha value if the side menu is opened and revert it back if the side menu is closed.

I have created the side menu using the source code given in the following link.
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/30/google-nexus-website-menu/

In CSS:

```
body {
  background: rgba(1,1,1,0);
}
```

I have used the class gn-menu for side menu and changed the alpha value in

```
body.gn-menu gn-open-all {
   background: rgba(1,1,1,0.8);
}
```

also tried opacity in

```
body.gn-menu gn-open-all {
   -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

If I gave this in the class gn-menu gn-open-all, then background-color will be changed for the items in the menu.

But the alpha value didn't changed.

How can I change the alpha value?

Thanks.

Comment: You should provide some code!

Comment: If you can show your code. It would be easy to help.

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi Edited the question. Please check it

Comment: @Newbie7988, can you tell me how do you open and close this side menu? Provide to me that JQuery code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your css rule is wrong if your purpose is to change the opacity of the entire  tag.

Solution:

```
body {
  background: rgba(1,1,1,0);
}

body.opened-menu {
  background: rgba(1,1,1,0.8);
}
```

Then modify the _openMenu/_closeMenu function to add the `opened-menu` class to the body. You could use jQuery or plain javascript.

```
_openMenu : function() {
    if( this.isMenuOpen ) return;
    classie.add( this.trigger, 'gn-selected' );
    this.isMenuOpen = true;
    classie.add( this.menu, 'gn-open-all' );
    //add class to body
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].classList.add("opened-menu")
    this._closeIconMenu();
},
_closeMenu : function() {
    if( !this.isMenuOpen ) return;
    classie.remove( this.trigger, 'gn-selected' );
    this.isMenuOpen = false;
    classie.remove( this.menu, 'gn-open-all' );
    //remove class to body
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].classList.remove("opened-menu")
    this._closeIconMenu();
}
```

Simone

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by adding a css class to your body container when side menu is open and then remove it when side menu is closed. And by catching that css class you can change the alpha of your container.